# How do I detect if Sails is started in interactive mode?

Tags: node.js, console, sails.js, command-line-interface

I have a hook, from which I want to detect if Sails is run in interactive mode (i.e. `sails console`) or in normal mode. How do I do this?

Comment: Sails is using default NodeJS `repl` module - https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html. I'm not sure, but if you can determine that this module is running then your question is solved :)